# x509 signing git commits results in verified on one machine, but suddenly unverified on the other

Tags: git, github, commit, x509, smimesign

Since about a year I use git commit signing with our official x509 certs without any problems.

Until last week everything was fine and I had verified commits, then I updated to macOS 14.0=>14.1 and git 2.41.0=>2.42.0 on my M2 Mac and suddenly my new commits were unverified, here an example of two git tag commits on GitLab with same cert and issuer, still one unverified, while the other is verified (the cert itself is valid for 2 more years).
[image: two git tag commits on GitLab with same cert and issuer, still one unverified, while the other is verified]

Things I checked:

- I deleted and reinstalled the cert: unverified
- I tried same cert on my old MacBook (Intel), both run on macOS 14.1 with git 2.42.0 and smimesign 0.2.0: **verified** (!!!).
- a local `git log --show-signature` shows good signatures for commits created with my GitHub-unverified Mac as well as for my GitHub-verified Mac.

As GitHub and GitLab behave the same concerning this, I use GitLab as a reference, because the later outputs the actual signing key, so eases debugging a bit: https://gitlab.com/jpmschuler/commitsigntest/-/commits/main?ref_type=heads

However I am out of ideas now. The signature in itself seems correct as the local checks work, so I can rule out a metadata mismatch during a rebase or similar. And the keys are the same and the chain seems to be identifiable and seems to be trusted in general. From my understanding of crypto this is about it that needs to match, but still: unverified.

Anybody any clue what to look for?